# MaterialTimePicker как получить AM PM из поля ввода

Tags: android

**MaterialTimePicker** как получить AM PM из поля ввода

Собственно может плохо искал,
нужно получить состояние АМ или ПМ при режиме ввода `setTimeFormat(TimeFormat.CLOCK_12H)`

`addOnPositiveButtonClickListener` возвращает только `hour, minute`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Все гораздо проще оказалось

метод `setTimeFormat` который принимает `TimeFormat.CLOCK_24H` или `TimeFormat.CLOCK_12H` меняет только интерфейс. но при выборе 10 ПМ, например, возвращается 20. То есть меняется только внешний вид. Время всегда возвращается в одном формате.